# Using Transloadit, How do you encode a video without resizing it?

Tags: video, resize, transloadit

I want to encode videos using transloadit, but i don't want to change their dimensions.

Checking the docs for the ffmpeg parameter it says if you set the value to null, you'll clear the default from the preset.

This doesn't seem to work with the "s" parameter however...
https://transloadit.com/assemblies/2328d183d7e14f4593c24def2c51b49b
I'm getting this error.. "Invalid frame size: null."
Am i missing something? Or is there an alternative workaround to achieve a "no resize" option when encoding videos?

```
"mp4-no-resize": {
      "use": ":original",
      "robot": "/video/encode",
      "ffmpeg_stack": "v2.2.3",
      "preset": "android",
      "rotate": false,
      "ffmpeg": {
        "s": "null"
      }
}
```

ffmpeg version 2.2.3-transloadit-static-v2.2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jun 3 2014 14:36:03 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
configuration: --disable-devices --disable-doc --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-shared --enable-bzlib --enable-gpl --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-static --enable-version3 --enable-zlib --extra-cflags='-I/usr/src/ffmpeg-static/target/include -static' --extra-cflags=--static --extra-ldflags='-L/usr/src/ffmpeg-static/target/lib -lm -lopus -static' --extra-libs='-lfontconfig -lfreetype -lexpat -lpng -lfribidi -xml2' --extra-version=transloadit-static-v2.2.3 --prefix=/usr/src/ffmpeg-static/target
libavutil 52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
libavcodec 55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
libavformat 55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
libavdevice 55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
libavfilter 4. 2.100 / 4. 2.100
libswscale 2. 5.102 / 2. 5.102
libswresample 0. 18.100 / 0. 18.100
libpostproc 52. 3.100 / 52. 3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/srv/shared/tmp/scratch/f7dd12d38eeb4567be72b38dcd35ecd9':
Metadata:
major_brand : mp42
minor_version : 1
compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
creation_time : 2019-05-01 10:18:28
Duration: 00:00:04.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2668 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2615 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2019-05-01 10:18:28
handler_name : Core Media Video
Invalid frame size: null.
Conversion failed!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the files original height/width by specifying them with file.meta placeholders.

```
"height": "${file.meta.height}"
"width": "${file.meta.width}"
```

Comment: Yes, and with later stacks you could also use an ‘empty’ preset and fill out all the ffmpeg parameters yourself (except size), but that’s more cumbersome. Your approach of nullifying is also interesting, but you should pass null then, and not the string “null”. Still, I think passing in meta like you did is best!